# Teams app customization by clients (icon and app name) are reset to default icon and name

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have had an issue recently with our clients using our Teams app `Ideas by Sideways 6`. Our clients customize our app by changing the icons and name. However recently many of our clients have had their icons and name reset to the default icon and name (i.e. their customization has been deleted), effectively reverting their icon to our icon and their app name to `Ideas by Sideways 6`.

This happened exactly the same time that we had our new Teams manifest approved and published. It seems like the issue is due to some error on the Microsoft side from publishing the new Teams manfiest.

Can you please look into this for us? We can give you the timestamps and details of clients that were affected.

Comment: The same issue has been reported here - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/9080. Could you please confirm if the issue is resolved?